# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS sound problem

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on imac but sound does not work. The information  of my system is under below:

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`lspci | grep Audio`:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

`grep "Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*`:

```
/proc/asound/card0/codec#0:Codec: Intel Broadwell HDMI
/proc/asound/card1/codec#0:Codec: Cirrus Logic CS4208
```

`lsmod | grep snd`:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    20480  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hda_intel          40960  10
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  28 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4208 Analog [CS4208 Analog]
```